# Using $set to update a document's value with key containing a dot(.), MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have this very basic collection (`blog.posts`) from which I want to update the value of a key (`author.name`) using the `$set` modifier. Here is a sample of a document from the collection:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ca66e7d8a3bb6e58e0d85f4"),
        "s_id": "unique_post",
        "title" : "MongoDB is cool",
        "author.name" : "Terence"
}
```

I want to change the value of the `author.name` key from **Terence** to **Benjamin** and this is the query with which I'm trying to acheive the result:

```
db.blog.posts.update({"s_id": "unique_post"}, {"$set":{"author.name":"Benjamin"}})
```

The issue is that when I execute this query, I end up with a new nested ducument as shown:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ca66e7d8a3bb6e58e0d85f4"),
        "title" : "MongoDB is cool",
        "author.name" : "Terence",
        "author" : {
                "name" : "Benjamin"
        }
}
```

I know that this is to be expected but my question is: **How do I modify a value in a document who's key contains a dot(.) ?**
 
Please I'm new to mongoDB and any other tips would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names) **dot(.)**  is a restricted character in field names. So you cannot have dot(.) in field names. That is the reason it converts the dot(.) value into subdocument.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this @Mani